# setcookie not working when defined with '/' but working if not defined

Tags: cookies

I have a very strange problem. I have this code in my functions.php. I followed the instructions and placed this code in the functions.php that was available in my theme folder in wp-content/themes/u-design/functions.php. For reference, my theme is u-design.

```
add_action('init', 'setmyCookie');
function setmyCookie(){
    //if(!isset($_COOKIE['myCookie'])){

        setcookie('myCookie', $_GET['test'], time() + 63072000, '/');
    //}
}
```

So what this does is to get the value from a query string and place that value in a cookie, for e.g.

```
www.mysite.com/?test=test
```

However, it does not work. But when I change the code to

```
add_action('init', 'setmyCookie');
function setmyCookie(){
    //if(!isset($_COOKIE['myCookie'])){

        setcookie('myCookie', $_GET['test'], time() + 63072000);
    //}
}
```

The cookie is being set! Why is this happening?

As of now, with the second method, although the cookie is being set, I can't use it as $_cookie['test'] is not returning the value in the cookie. From what I googled, this is because the cookie is only being set at the current path. To use $_cookie['myCookie'], you have to set the cookie such that it is available throughout the domain. However, if I do that, as in the first method, the cookie isn't being set at all!

Does anyone know why is this happening and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Your code Fatal Errors altogether for me, I guess because of the function name. Is it the _actual_ name you are trying to use?

Comment: oh no I edited the function name. I'm actually using another name. Edited the post to make it clearer. Sorry!

Comment: What happens if you use the `COOKIEPATH` constant?

Comment: This is a generic PHP question, I don't where WordPress is involved in your issue. Anyway, your code is working perfectly. You can not use `$_cookie['test']` because the name of the cookie is not "test", it is "mycookie".

Comment: I double-checked my code and it's just an error when I was typing out my question. My apologies, I was using $_cookie['myCookie'] and it wasn't working, hence my question still stands. Also, I have also checked if the cookie was set and it isn't, doesn't that point to an error to the setcookie method? The line of code that includes '/' as the fourth parameter doesn't work, yet the line of code that has only three parameters (the second example) works in setting the cookie.

Comment: It perhaps may not be a Wordpress issue, but as every guide I've read on setting cookies in php says, and you also state that the code should be working perfectly, I was unsure if there is something with Wordpress that stops it from working. I have tested setcookie and $_cookie directly in an otherwise empty php file with only those two methods and it works fine there, so I'm considering the possibility that the error lies elsewhere.

Comment: check this link http://allinonescript.com/questions/8890115/php-cookies-are-not-being-set